# My DOS crashes everytime I gave large input set for my C++ program

Tags: c++, windows, dos

I have written a code in C++ and tried to compile it using MinGW and TDMGCC compiler. It get compiles very well. But the problem occurs when i tried to use .exe file generated by these compiler and i give a large input set to my program my dos stops working and says windows has stopped working. After clicking on OK it terminates my execution. How can i fix it.
Here is my code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int t,n,k,c,x,w;
    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open ("example.txt");
    cin>>t;
    for(w=1;w<=t;w++)
    {
        cin>>n>>k>>c>>x;
        int a[n],b[n],array[n][n];
        for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
            cin>>a[i];
        for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
            cin>>b[i];
        for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
        {
            for(int j=1;j<=n;j++)
            {
                array[i][j]=(a[i]*i+b[j]*j+c)%x;
            }
        }

        int re[1000],z=0;
        if(k>1){
        for(int i=1;i+k-1<=n;i++)
        {
            for(int j=1;j+k-1<=n;j++)
            {
                re[z]=array[i][j]+array[i][j+1]+array[i+1][j]+array[i+1][j+1];

                z++;
            }
        }}

        else
        {
            for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
            {
                for(int j=1;j<=n;j++)
                {
                    re[z]=array[i][j];
                    z++;
                }
            }
        }


        int lar=re[0];
        for(int i=1;i<z;i++)
        {
            if(re[i]>lar)
                lar=re[i];
        }
        myfile<<"Case #"<<w<<": "<<lar<<endl;
    }
    myfile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @vishal check it out

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit yes When i execute my program on DOS( say main.exe) it display an error message like main.exe has stopped working and after that it terminates my execution automatically.

Comment: Why (how?!) are you executing programs on DOS? Windows and Linux were invented a long time ago.

Comment: I think the OP is using the wrong term. This is just a console application under windows. Not a dos application.

Comment: I specifically have to write a code in gcc compiler that can execute code by taking a very large input and store result in a file. Do you have any solution for my problem/?

Comment: I think your problem is caused by using a VLA when you should be using a std::vector.

Comment: What inputs are you supplying to your program?  FYI `int a[n],b[n],array[n][n];` is non standard and should not be used.

Answer (score 2):

You have a basic off-by-one error:

```
    int a[n],b[n],array[n][n];
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
        cin>>a[i];
```

`a` has length `n`, meaning valid indices are between `0` and `n-1` inclusive. You're writing a value at index `n`, which is past the end.

Structure your loops like this instead:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cin >> a[i];
```

All your loops show this problem.

Also, like @NathanOliver says, use `std::vector` instead of variable-length arrays (VLA). VLA is in the C standard, but it's not in C++. So your use of it here is non-standard. Simply add `#include <vector>` and replace

```
int a[n];
```

with

```
std::vector<int> a(n);
```

and everything else can stay the same.